# wrong time format in different windows for rtl languages

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have a .NET 2015 C# application that runs fine on Windows 8.
I run it on Windows 7 and the date time picker that has been formated to HH:mm displayed as mm:HH.

Is there an answer for that problem?

Comment: I think the problem is also on for textboxes! (22+":"+15) shows (15:22) in 7

Comment: would u share the code?

Comment: dt1.CustomFormat = "mm:HH";
dt1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dt1.ShowUpDown = true;

Comment: It's not about the code, it's something about rtl language maybe
I use persian and english, and my form layout is set to rtl